# System.NullPointerException test class while calling method for test coverage

Tags: apex

```
global with sharing class Information{

@HttpGet
global static ResultWrapper doGet() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    ResultWrapper objResultWrapper = new ResultWrapper();

    string caseAsset = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    try {
    objResultWrapper.caseCount = [SELECT COUNT() From Case  WHERE Asset.Count__c = :caseAsset ];

     }
      catch (Exception ex) {
     System.debug('Exception caught!!'+ex);

  }
    return objResultWrapper;
}


global class ResultWrapper {
 public Integer caseCount = 0;
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
private class CustomerCaseInformationTest
{
    static testMethod void testMainMethod()
    {
        Case cse = new Case();
    cse.Status='New';
    cse.Priority='Medium';
    cse.Origin = 'Email';

    insert cse;
            Case cs =[SELECT id, CaseNumber FROM Case limit 1];
           Information.doGet(); ///// null pointer exception here in test[how to call this method inside test class] class

     Information.ResultWrapper innerClass = new Information.ResultWrapper();
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.requestUri ='/services/apexrest/api/Case/New';
    request.httpMethod = 'GET';
    RestContext.request = request;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because You are first calling the method and then passing the values.

```
Information.doGet();
```

So you are getting error here

```
req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Because currently `req is null.`

You need to change the order

```
Information.ResultWrapper innerClass = new Information.ResultWrapper();
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.requestUri ='/services/apexrest/api/Case/New';
request.httpMethod = 'GET';
RestContext.request = request;
Information.doGet();
```